# ペイパルでの定期支払で決済を繰り越した場合

Tags: paypal

未決済分を次月へ繰り越した場合、PayPalの残高に2カ月分の残高が無い場合は決済エラーとなるのか？それとも1ヶ月分のみ決済されることがあるか？

Answer (score 1):

2ヶ月分の残高がない場合はエラーになります。1ヶ月分のみの決済はされません。
なお、繰越金額のみの決済を行いたい場合には、BillOutstandingAmount APIを使うといいですよ。

BillOutstandingAmount API
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/BillOutstandingAmount_API_Operation_NVP/

Answer (score 1):

デベロッパーには登録済みでしょうか？
詳しくはこちらに聞くといいですよ。
https://www.paypal.com/jp/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/devcentral_landing-outside